# Add key in known_hosts file in ChromeOS

Tags: ssh, google-chrome-os

With the very limited ChromeOS crosh shell, how do I add a host key to my known_hosts file in ChromeOS.

Comment: SSH adds the host key to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` automatically when you try to connect for the first time after prompting you, doesn't it?

Comment: I have created a virtual host whose entry i want to add in the known_hosts file of other systems, that's why i need that.